# IIS 8 : Asp.Net Web Application Deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I have deployed an Asp.Net application as a website on IIS 8. But I am receiving error "The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" could not be located"
Commenting below lines dosent work

```
  <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
          <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
          <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
        </compilers>
      </system.codedom>
```

Anybody faced same issue.

Comment: delete your /packages folder under sln directory as well as /bin and /obj under UI directory and retry.

Comment: @Nathan There is no packages folder..only packages file

Comment: Also when I am deploying it as web application..it works fine but not accessible on another machine.

Comment: Could you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

I have this trouble to , Fixed by update package.

> Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem in local development on Visual Studio 2015.
I resolved it by cleaning the solution in Menu "Build/Clean Solution" then "Built/Rebuilt Solution" and it is working fine again.

Hope to help :)